# Javascript: Get value without ID

Tags: javascript, getelementsbyclassname

```
<div class="CurrencyQuote">


<div class="column">
    <div class="form-label">Pair: </div><div>BUX/TIX</div>
    <div class="form-label padding-top">Spread: </div><div>113</div>
</div>
<div class="column">
    <div class="form-label">Rate: </div><div>10.159/10.272</div>
    <div class="form-label padding-top">High/Low: </div><div>115</div>
</div>

</div>
```

I would like to get the value 113 and also the value 115, but how do I do it without ID in javascript? I can't change the HTML and I need to get those 2 values separately, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var query = document.querySelectorAll('.column > .form-label');
for(var i=0,l=query.length;i<l;++i){
    if(query[i].innerHTML == 'Spread: '
    || query[i].innerHTML == 'High/Low: '
    ) console.log(query[i].nextElementSibling.innerHTML)
}
```

Comment: `nextElementSibling` is not that widely supported yet.

Comment: @Jack MDN doesn't list any compatibility table.

Comment: @JanDvorak That doesn't say much :) It's [IE9+](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-sg/library/ie/ff974796(v=vs.85).aspx) for one.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Document.querySelector) and build up a unique path to your elements using CSS selectors like this:

```
var els = document.querySelectorAll( '.column .form-label.padding-top ~ div' );

for( var i=els.length; i--; ) {
  console.log( els[i].innerHTML );
}
```

---

<sup>To make all jQuery fans happy as well:</sup>

```
$( '.column .form-label.padding-top ~ div' ).each( function() { console.log( this.text() ); } );
```

Comment: It is possible to get it separately?

Comment: @user2276965 What do you mean by "seperatly"? Instead of the `console.log()` you can forward the values individually to any function or code you like.

Comment: I meant by, is it possible to get only 1 of the value only?

Comment: @user2276965 you mean, by not looping? As in, `els[0]` and `els[1]`?

Answer (score 0):

With JQuery you can do it like

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".padding-top").each(function(){
     alert($(this).next().html());
    });

});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/WYSd4/

Answer (score 0):

This should be pretty compatible with any kind of browser; it searches all elements with `column` class, then finds the last `<div>` child:

```
var columns = document.getElementsByClassName('column'),
values = [];

for (var i = 0, n = columns.length; i != n; ++i) {
  var node = columns[i].lastChild;
  // find last div child
  while (node && node.nodeName != 'DIV') {
    node = node.previousSibling;
  }
  if (node) {
    values.push(node.textContent || node.innerText || '');
  }
}

console.log(values);
```